# C++ Time complexity in Oh notation of recursive function with for loop

Tags: recursion, time, complexity-theory

What would the time complexity for the following function in Oh-Notation?

```html
void fun(int n)
{
if (n <= 1)
  return;
fun(n − 1);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  cout << " * ";
}
```

I would assume it is O(n), but I may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `O(n^2)`, since increasing n results in both increasing the number of the `for`-calls, as well as the required time for each `for`-loop to finish.

Both changes rise linear, resulting to the formula `O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be `O(n)` without the recursion.
Consider this call stack for fun(3):

```
fun(3): 
    fun(2):
       fun(1):
            return;
    cout " * * "
cout " * * * "
```